# python to find the oldest person in the state with the lowest average

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming and I understand for loops, if/else statements and a bit of dictionaries. I don't mind coding things myself but I am having hard time figuring out the logic.

Problem statement - find the oldest person in the state with the lowest average age from this file.

I am able to iterate over the entire list and get all the entries printed out. But not sure how to find the oldest person with the lowest average... which is per state.

sample data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "state": "Connecticut",
    "age": 95
  },
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "state": "Maine",
    "age": 82
  },
  {
    "name": "qwr",
    "state": "Missouri",
    "age": 56
  },
  {
    "name": "qwer",
    "state": "Maryland",
    "age": 56
  },
  {
    "name": "asdf",
    "state": "Rhode Island",
    "age": 17
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, could you clarify what you mean by "lowest average age"? Do you mean that you want to find 1.) the oldest person in the entire list, and also 2.) the state that has the lowest average age? In that case, you can do something like this:

```py
def get_oldest_citizen(data):
    return max(data, key=lambda citizen: citizen.age)

def get_state_with_youngest_average_age(data):
    state_ages = {}
    for citizen in data:
        if citizen.state in state_ages:
            state_ages[citizen.state] += [citizen.age]
        else:
            state_ages[citizen.state] = [citizen.age]
    for state, ages in state_ages.items():
        state_ages[state] = sum(ages) / len(ages)

    return min(state_ages.values())
```

There's definitely a more concise and pythonic way to do the second one, but it gets the basic idea across -- basically just keep track of all citizens of a given state's ages, then take the average once you've recorded them all and find the youngest of those.

***Edit 1:*** I realized now what you mean, that you want to find the oldest citizen *in* the state that has the lowest average age. In that case, all you have to do is use these two functions together, supplying the first with data you can find from the second.

Comment: I re-read the OP question and it reads that you find the average age per state. then once you know the state with the lowest average age you should select the oldest person from that state

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange your data by state. Then use min and lambda to find the lowest average state. then max and lambda to find theoldest person in that state.

```py
data = [
  {"name": "xyz", "state": "Connecticut", "age": 95},
  {"name": "abc", "state": "Maine", "age": 82},
  {"name": "qwr", "state": "Missouri", "age": 56},
  {"name": "qwer", "state": "Maryland", "age": 22},
  {"name": "asdf", "state": "Rhode Island", "age": 57},
  {"name": "adam", "state": "Maryland", "age": 14},
]

from collections import defaultdict
data_by_state = defaultdict(list)
for record in data:
    data_by_state[record["state"]].append(record)

lowest_avg_age_state = min(data_by_state, key=lambda state: sum([record["age"] for record in data_by_state[state]]) / len(data_by_state[state]))
print(f"{lowest_avg_age_state=}")
oldest_person_in_state = max(data_by_state[lowest_avg_age_state], key=lambda record: record["age"])
print(f"{oldest_person_in_state['name']=}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
lowest_avg_age_state='Maryland'
oldest_person_in_state['name']='qwer'
```